# JLCTREE package in R

Tags: r

I am working on a joint latent class tree model, and I have used the jlctree package in R, but I am facing challenges in predicting the classes. I have included the code and sample data.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/")
library(haven)
projectdata <-read_dta("sample.dta")
#View(projectdata)                       



library(jlctree)
library(survival)
library(rpart)
library(lme4)
library(Matrix)

attach(projectdata)


 

tree <- jlctree(survival =(Surv(duration_icu_1, icu_discharge_death)~hypertension + gender + age_at_admission_in_comple + lymphocytes+neutrophils+crp),
classmb=~hypertension + gender + diab_mellitus, fixed=tropt~ lymphocytes+neutrophils+crp +pro + ddimer + age_at_admission_in_comple, random=~1,
subject='hospital_number',projectdata,parms=list(min.nevents=10, fity=FALSE,fits=FALSE))
```

Suggested to use

```
predict_class(tree$tree, projectdata)
```

Unfortunately, this function is no longer working. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Detailed information is provided: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jlctree/versions/0.0.2/topics/jlctree-package

Comment: The paper was written by Ningshan Zhang and Jeffrey S. Simonoff: Joint Latent Class Trees: A Tree-Based Approach to Joint Modeling of Time-to-event and Longitudinal Data. arXiv:1812.01774 (2018).